# How to get parameters name and value from function when pass By ...$args or func_get_args()

Tags: php, function, class, methods, arguments

I want get name and value of function parameters by `..$arg` or `func_get_args()`

I don't want use `compact` function and `args_with_keys` not correct work

I tried `debug_backtrace()[0]['args']` and `get_defined_vars()` but It didn't work

```
 $color = 'blue';
 $size = '40cm';

 function data(){
 print_r(func_get_args());
 }

 data($color,$size); //array("color"=>"blue","size"=>"40cm")
```

OR

```
 $color = 'blue';
 $width = '40cm';
 $height = '50cm';

 function data(...$args){
      print_r($args);
 }

 data($color,$size); //array("color"=>"blue","width"=>"40cm","height"=>"50cm")
```

I tried this But get me numeric key of arguments but I want get parameters name and value like above example

Thank You

Comment: @nigel-ren I already read this link, and this link not answer me, I don't want use compact method and args_with_keys function get me numeric keys array

Comment: If you read the duplicate, you will notice that the accepted answer is that there is no way to do this directly.  The other solutions are just work arounds.